# Python "Totem" Locations (Platform independent Paths)

Tags: python, windows, caching, path, default

So I want my program, when packed into an .exe and ran on any system (Mainly Windows) that doesn't have Python installed, to ***write a hidden temporary file*** somewhere in the file system (Preferably high up in the System Tree that wont be at risk for accidental removal) as a way to know when it was first run, like a totem.
... and what I mean by "Totem" is like that silver dreidel from Inception that Leonardo DiCaprio used to know what state he was in (REM, or Reality); for lack of a better word/metaphor.

For example in Windows Command Prompt, you can use PATH variables to get default paths for things like the users home location:

```
start cmd
echo "%USERPROFILE%
```

... and that would return something like "C:/Users/Chris", and that would be perfect cause I would have:

```
a. Sufficient Read/Write privileges
b. In a directory that won't be removed any time soon.
```

The closest thing I found was to use:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

But that would return a list of random paths, most of which reside within the Python default directory, and I don't want this "Totem" too high up in the tree in case of insufficient Write privileges, and raise:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

So I need a consistent default path that will have sufficient privileges for reading/writing files without the need for external libraries.

Comment: `sys.path` is defiantly __not__ what you need as it is where python searches for executable & library files - you should not normally be writing to any of these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you use appdirs: `pip install appdirs`

This will provide you with a set of functions to determine the correct paths to use in a platform agnostic manner.

- `appdirs.user_data_dir()` will give you the user data directory
- `appdirs.user_config_dir()` will give you the user configuration directory
- `appdirs.user_cache_dir()` you got it

All of which you should have sufficient privileges to write to but with appropriate naming, e.g. *.YourAppName.totem* you should find that it is not randomly deleted. Prefixing with . on most systems will make the file invisible but on windows you may also need to actively hide the file.

Comment: Appdirs? Is that an external module? Cause I want this to have no third party modules... As mentioned, I want this program to run on a variety of systems without dependencies.

Comment: Appdirs is a cross platform library that you could make a pre-requisite or you could ship it with your application by downloading it from https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs and putting it, all 557 lines, into your app directory. BTW your question doesn't say no dependencies.

Comment: Okay, I updated my question. But this module is pretty cool... It is a bit bulky, and not the easiest solution was hoping for, but if it works on other platforms (Which I'll have to assume given I can't test it myself), I could easily pack it into an .exe with py2exe since it doesn't require a mess of other pre-requisites! -Thanks! :)

Comment: @ChrisNguyen It definitely works on Windows XP..10, OS-X and Linux systems __but__ you cannot use py2exe for non-windows platforms - pyinstaller or cxfreeze are good alternatives.

Comment: You shouldn't use "." prefixed names in this case. On Linux you'll be accessing, for example,  `~/.local/share`, and its subdirectories shouldn't be hidden. This way you also never have to set the hidden attribute in Windows, which would just cause headaches when replacing files (attributes have to match, else `CreateFile` errors out).

Comment: Ignore the warning in the source to avoid `site_data_dir` on Windows. It's normal for applications to use `%ProgramData%` on Vista+. It's hidden, but so is the user's `%AppData%` directory. The ACL on this directory grants users read and execute permissions. They also have permission to create files and directories, to which they're granted full control, but that's problematic for *other* users, who won't be able to write to, replace, or delete those files. I recommend treating the application's directory here like the equivalent `/usr/share` directory on Unix.